# WAMP and WIN 8 issues on port 80

Tags: php, mysql, port, wamp

I have tried all to get WAMP running in WIN 8 due to the problems on port 80. I changed the settings in lmhost from 80 to 8080 but I get a error localhost 8080 is not allowed....

I am using chrome as a browser.

Thanks in advance for any assistance, this is holding me up and I feel like dropping win 8!

Oh, I also edited my Windows HOSTS file; it looks like so:
127.0.0.1      localhost : 8080

and my httpd like so:

    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

I also replaced "http://localhost" in wampmanger.tpl like so:
"http://localhost :8080"

Stupid from MS to do this!!!!

Comment: AFAIK, XAMPP has better win8 integration at the moment...